# Veeam backup iSCSI drive

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, veeam

We have an ESXi virtual machine currently being backed up using Veeam B&R 6.5.

The virtual server itself has an ISCSI drive attached (Windows iSCSI Initiator), but it is not included within the backup job (only the C:\ drive included).  Can someone please tell me how I can add this iSCSI drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veeam B&R utilizes VMware's backup APIs in order to provide backups of virtual disks. It is not a generalized host backup product, and it cannot take backups of guest-mounted iSCSI volumes.

If you want Veeam to back up this drive, you'll need to attach it as an RDM (Raw Device Mapping) in Virtual mode from the hypervisor side instead of attaching it via the guest iSCSI initiator. Note that you cannot use Virtual mode for a disk used in Microsoft Clustering Services.

Answer (score 5):

For many people it makes sense to use [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/overview.html) to convert the iSCSI drive to a VMDK and store it in a similar location to the virtual machine itself.  We choose to do this to allow that machine to be consistent with the configuration of other virtual machines in the environment, however you can opt to use an RDM as well.

With RDM the maximum volume size can be 2TB-512B or 64TB, depending on version and RDM type.  See the [configuration maximums](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere5/r50/vsphere-50-configuration-maximums.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Good point about the max size on an RDM.